# I need to split the bulk data into 2 DB's as current and history

Tags: sql

```
**

**if (month(getdate())=01) and (day(getdate())=01)
declare @i as datetime
declare @j as datetime
set @i = getdate()
set @j=select year(@i)-3
---set @j=@i
---set @i
select '@j'+''+'dec'+''+'31'
select distinct * into <destination> from <source> where <datecolumn><= '@j'+'-'+'dec'+'-'+'31'**
```

**

This is what i have done upto now, but the thing is i need to append data to history from current, every year

Comment: Why not just `INSERT INTO <destination> SELECT DISTINCT * FROM <source> WHERE ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO <destination> 
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM <source> 
WHERE <datecolumn> <= @j + '-dec-31'
```

Note that your original syntax is treating `@j` as a *literal* string rather than replacing it  with the numeric year value.